# Power supply shuts off when attached to a specific notebook

Tags: laptop, power-supply

I have a notebook that seems to cause a short, but I'm not sure

- how to verify it as the root problem
- how to fix it

The behaviour is the following:

1. I take a working power supply/cable from some notebook.
2. I plug the cable into the defect notebook. The power supply immediately shuts off, which is visible as a little LED is turned off. The notebook does not charge.
3. I unplug the PSU from notebook and wall socket and wait a few seconds
4. I plug the PSU into the socket again, the light turns on and the PSU seems to be working like it should for other notebooks.

Please note, that the notebooks are of the same model and I use an OEM's power cabel that was bundled with these devices.

Answer (score 1):

I think you've verified it with the testing you've described already.

You may have something as simple as loose solder joints on the power connector if it's soldered onto the laptop's system board.  From my experience, to fix it is going to require a fairly complete disassembly of the laptop and a knowledge of how to resolder pins which run through a PCB to a solder pad.

None of that is rocket science, but I'd encourage perhaps a bit of trial and error on a piece of electronics you don't care about just to get familiar with the process if you've not done this type of soldering before.